# Autocomplete in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, autocomplete, silverlight-toolkit

I have `Listbox` in my WP7 page like this

```
   <ListBox Name="lstSelectedNumber" Height="50" MaxHeight="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="lstSelectedNumber_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-15" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <toolkit:WrapPanel>
                                </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="acBox" FilterMode="StartsWith" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

My `Listbox` is attached to my collection `List<SampleData>`

Like `lstSelectedNumber.itemsource = List<SampleData>;`

And for my autocompletebox I want to bind my auto completebox to other collection List so when the user type in my textbox it shows suggestion to user and once user select to any item it adds this item to my other collection List
I am facing one problem: how can I bind my list to the autocompletbox which in the listbox so I can do further proceedings?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to find my listbox control in this way but its returning me 0 always for childs

```
 private void SearchVisualTree(DependencyObject targetElement)
        {
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(targetElement);
            if (count == 0)
                return;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(targetElement, i);
                if (child is AutoCompleteBox)
                {
                    AutoCompleteBox myItems = (AutoCompleteBox)child;

                    if (myItems.Name == "acBox")
                    {
                       // My Logic
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SearchVisualTree(child);
                }
            }
        }
```

and in this way I'm calling on my page constructor

```
SearchVisualTree(this.lstSelectedNumber);
```

Comment: It seems to be something wrong with your Shift key. It seems to intermittently be stuck at every first character you type. Let me fix that for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
         List<WP7Phone> data = new List<WP7Phone>();

            foreach (lines l in result)
            {
                WP7Phone w7 = new WP7Phone();

                w7.Name = l.line.TrimStart();

                w7.Image = "images/thump.jpg";

                msg.Add(w7);
            }


            this.autoCompleteBox1.ItemsSource = data;


   public class WP7Phone
 {
    public string Name
  {
    get;
    set;
}
public string Image1
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

}

Comment: Senthil Kumar This is Not What As I Asked In My Question Problem is How To Bind Data To AutoComplete Textbox Which is Inside The Listbox And Both Have Differant Data Sources. And Even I Cant Assign Direct DataSoutce By Calling Its Name Of Autocomplete Box As Its Inside the DataTemplate of Listbox